# Python function does not return value after few successful runs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have weird problem with my function.

When I call function _read_page it works fine.
When I run code below with loop it works but only for few iteration and then it breaks.
When I call each row in "while loop" it works but after few iteration function _read_page does not return any value and does not assign it to y. But it seems to be fine, function _read_page does not return any error. Thereafter next step pd.concat returns error about NoneType object.

Important is when I call _read_page again with the same parameters it returns value and value is assign to y.

**EDIT:**
it ends on the command `fin = req.json()`

Do you know what is the problem?
Can it be caused by something with memory or by something like this? 
Thank you and sorry for my English...

```py
...
x_df = pd.DataFrame()
first_pass = True
y = {"total_count": 0}
continuous_count = 0
while first_pass or continuous_count < y["total_count"]: 
    first_pass = False
    y = _read_page(pods_url=pods_url,
                   auth=auth,
                   data=data)
    x_df = pd.concat([x_df,
                      y["data"]["Data"]], ignore_index=False)
    scroll_id = y["data"]["ScrollId"][0]
    data["ScrolledFilterRequest"].update({"ScrollId": scroll_id})
    continuous_count = continuous_count + page_size
...
```

```py
def _read_page(pods_url, auth, data, dataframe=True):
try:
    url = pods_url + "api/v1/Catalog/NestScrollApi"
    req = requests.post(url=url, auth=auth, verify=False, json=data)
    if req.status_code != 200:
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        fin = {"TotalCount": 0}
    else:
        fin = req.json()
        df = pd.DataFrame(fin)
    return {"data": df,
            "total_count": fin["TotalCount"],
            "response": req.status_code}
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Is the `data` you are using for API call is same for every iteration? if no then can you check if this error comes for some specific dataset. if `data` is same for every API call then whether continuous calling of  `"api/v1/Catalog/NestScrollApi"` in loop is allowed?

Comment: data is the same for every iteration only with small change,  specifically scroll_id is changed. But it has to work for each scroll_id. I tested it with Swagger in the browser and it works fine for the same data and scroll_id. I think that continuous calling in loop is allowed too, because it made mare than 10 itteration and that breaks, somethimes more than 20 and than breaks. I am desperate because of no error message.

Comment: there is error in line `fin = req.json()`
`
in json
    self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs

MemoryError
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it is **MemoryError**.

There is error in line fin = req.json() `in json self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs MemoryError`

Solution is change the 32-bit version of Python to 64-bit version of Python and it works without problem, without change the code.